# Dynamic Selection of Polymer theme

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

I'm using `polymer` `style-modules` to implement theming. To do this I have packaged all the styles in a `dom-module`, like this:

```
<dom-module id='my-theme'>
 <template>
  <style>
    :root {
      --primary-text-color: yellow;

      ... more styles ..

    }

    ...

    paper-button.important {
      --paper-button-color: red;

      ... more styles ..

    }
  </style>
 </template>     
</dom-module>
```

Also made a `.dart` package to be imported in `index.dart`:

```
@HtmlImport("my-style.html")
library my_style.lib;

import 'package:web_components/web_components.dart' show HtmlImport;
```

Then in the `index.html` I will use it this way :

```
<link type='import' href='packages/my-style.html'>
<style is='custom-style' include='my-theme'></style>
```

Everything is working (don't care possible typos in the example above) even though I had to import the module with an html import and not in the usual dart way with a package import to make it work.

**The Question is** : this is working with a fixed theme. Is there a way to switch theme dynamically ? i.e. doings something like :

```
<style is='custom-style' include='[[selectedTheme]]'></style>
```

Comment: Interesting question. In my case only a fixed thememing is needed. I have implemented a more primitive solution, with include of my-style in every element, this works. But could be nice to replace it with a single override in index.html. Does your implementation make <my-theme> override <default-theme> project wide? So when you implements new elements, they also get the override, without an include of my-style.html?

Comment: Yes. Styles are propagated down to every component in this way. But you have to put the HTML import in the ibdex explicitly

Comment: Yes it works. In index.html there was two lines invoking dart/js scripts, these should be moved up from the <body> section to the <head> section. Great.

Comment: My answer to this question shows how to change style-modules of components dynamically. If you only need this for the `<style is="custom-style>` added to `<head>` in `index.html` I guess it should work to modify the `include` attribute of the `<style is='custom-style' include='...'></style>`. If this doesn't work you might need to remove the existing tag and add a new one.